# Where can I find Manu Smriti with Sanskrit & Hindi translation?

Tags: scripture, translation-request, manu-smriti

I want Manu Smriti with Sanskrit slokas and their Hindi translation. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one Sanskrit text with Hindi translation of Manu Smriti by Pandit Girija Prasad Dvivedi on archive.org:

[ManuSmritHindi-GpDwivedi](https://archive.org/details/ManuSmritHindi-GpDwivedi)   (PDF: [ManuSmritHindi-GpDwivedi_text.pdf](https://archive.org/download/ManuSmritHindi-GpDwivedi/ManuSmritHindi-GpDwivedi_text.pdf))

---

The English translation of Manu Smriti is available at [sacred-texts.com](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/manu.htm) (George Bühler) and also on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/lawsofman00manu) (Max Müller).

EDIT:

Another English tr. of *Manusmriti with the Commentary of Medhatithi* is available at: [wisdomlib.org](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi#contents) (work in progress)