# Manu Smriti as a source of controversy

Tags: manu-smriti

Many contemporary groups (fundamentalist Christians and Muslims; secular liberals; Marxists) have denounced the "Manu Smriti" text as a source of discrimination against the "lesser castes" as well as against women.  One researcher from the Arya Samaj has said that the "Manu Smriti" text has been altered (via addition of later shlokas) throughout the centuries in order to give economic and political power to the Brahmins and Kshatriyas.  This same researcher states that the true and original verses of Lord Manu did not contain such discrimination and inequality.

What is the validity of such accusations and assertions? Please provide guidance to all the interested individuals of Hindu Dharma living abroad who don't have access to the primary textual sources of "Manu Smriti".

Comment: 1) And what parts of Hindu scripture do they not condemn?? 2) Have you read the Manu Smriti? It is an ancient text, with many parts meant for people of that time. The Old Testament of the Bible gives directions as to how a man should treat his young female slaves - what about that? 3) The laws of Manu are smriti, they are not sruti. If parts of it conflicts with sruti then reject it. All modern Vedanta rests on three legs - the Upanishads, the Gita, and the Brahma Sutras - no matter what your sect. Don't get lost in secondary texts.

Comment: @ Swami Vishwananda , Well Said.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Swami Vishwananda.  I definitely liked the part about Sruti taking predence over Smriti.  Vedanta views the Jivatma-Paramatma relationship as sacred.  The Jivatma is given sanctity so this is a most egalitarian metaphysical doctrine.  Can you suggest a good English-language translation of "Manu Smriti" (one which represents Lord Manu's intent for composing this Smriti)?  If there are annotations in the translation, then these will help to give a context for the verses.

Comment: @NehalPatel See [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12373/2995).

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, i need advice on day-to-day matters - how to divide inheritance, how to choose a bride/groom, how to clean myself after nature's call, what direction to keep my head while sleeping etc. Do Vedas have these ? If so, can you show me where ? The philosophy 'reject smriti if conflicting with sruti' was made famous by Swami Vivekananda (I read almost full CW and Ramakrishna Kathamrita end-to-end), but he didn't sweep all age-old wisdom under 'irrelevant for today'-carpet, which has lead to disastrous consequences. If u can show which Manu Smriti verses are against Vedas, pls do.

Comment: In the Dharma sastras such as Manu-smriti sages explained things which they learned from Sruti, and Itihasas, Pancaratras and sattvic Puranas such as Vishnu Purana and Bhagavatam are also written according to teachings of Sruti.

Comment: @ram Hinduism can do without the text offering such mechanical control of life. Religious texts are meant to be pondered and critiqued to obtain wisdom. Not to be used like an OS manual.

Comment: @tejasvi88, hmm.. a fitness athlete gives you a day-to-day, hour-by-hour exercise program (90 minute workout, 30-day fat loss) etc., and you lap it up without question.. why ? because you are interested in the results, right? do you know what majority of people call such people... 'suckers' . But do those 'suckers' who actually followed it, and verified the results for themselves, think of themselves as 'suckers' ? No. They think the rest of majority people are ignorant, lazy, sour-grapes foxes. Similarly, shastras are god-send for people interested in results. For others, they are 'OS manual'

Comment: @ram I would be much wary to take obscure and uncritiqued fitness advice which is dismissed by the rational majority. But that's irrelevant. I won't go as far either to call Manusmriti 'god-send'. Great piece of work by humans? Absolutely.

Comment: @tejasvi88, exactly - you will dismiss it, until you benefit from it. is there any point in the benefiters arguing with the doubters, when the benefiters themselves were doubters before, and the only thing that changed their stance is actually following said program ?

Comment: @ram I see what you're getting at. I would quote 'extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence'. If the components of an advice fail to support themselves, the efficacy of advice as whole, being unamenable to experiments, is indeed an extraordinary claim. Might I as well add placebo affect to the mix which would void the exclusiveness of benefits. The burden of proof lies on the benefiters (or claimers) because this situation is similar to the Russell's teapot.

Comment: 'extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence' ? 'extraordinary results require extraordinary effort'. btw, even Einstein cannot even prove a simple thing like 'mango tastes sweet' to me, if I refuse to taste it. Similarly, even Vyasa cannot prove that rebirth/karma/bhagavan exists to you, if you refuse to follow the method for verification. See - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34343/have-hindu-philosophies-dealt-with-subjective-vs-objective-pramana-evidence

Comment: @ram Glad to see such discussions still active in Hinduism even if I don't fully agree with it. The subjective method falls apart when there are handful of people claiming the opposite, the mango is salty. Assuming common connotation of words, is same mango now sweet or salty or something else? We can debate about the perfect method to know but reaching consensus purely through subjectivity is impossible (mango is poor eg here). As an aside, Invisible Pink Unicorn (yeah, it's real deal) also has a path of salvation if anyone is willing to verify.

Comment: @tejasvi88, "The subjective method falls apart when there are handful of people claiming the opposite," - there are people claiming the earth is flat.. does their subjective opinion invalidate the round-earth theory ? Or are those people either ignorant, or flawed in their experimentation ? Same way, people who claim shastras are wrong, are either ignorant, or flawed in their experimentation.

Comment: @ram Yes, it does invalidate the subjective opinion that earth is round (or hypercube) until it is objectively proven otherwise.

Comment: @tejasvi88, exactly. by that logic, every single thing that I have not personally verified myself is subject to doubt. And being scientific, I will refuse to believe it until evidence proves it true. Which means, that when a doctor gives me headache medicine, it is subjective opinion until I have verified all the pharmaceutical double-blind research studies myself. Until then I won't eat the medicine and suffer the headache.. right ?

Comment: @ram It's a non-sequitur about the application of objective methods on an individual level. _Trust_ is here a useful aid for acceptable levels of public scrutiny. Pushing the envelope thus further (say, trust sanity?) will invalidate the basis of argument and result in red herring.

Comment: "Trust is here a useful aid for acceptable levels of public scrutiny" - Exactly. Who you CHOOSE to TRUST is as subjective as the taste of a mango. You choose to trust scientists and denigrate rishis. I choose to trust rishis and treat scientists neutrally.

Comment: @mar look at comments below

Comment: @tejasvi88 look at comments below

Comment: I would argue that's a bit dogmatic if we look at Pramanas. Scientists using today's technology directly perceive and make observations of what they see. Then, they used inference-making theories supported by empirical evidence. As we can perceive things more accurately and scalably i.e. larger or smaller with technology we get a better understanding of this world. In my view, if a scripture goes against empirical evidence it must be reexamined, reinterpreted, and/or refuted. The Vedas are metaphorical in many cases hence their difficulty for us to understand.

Comment: Their poetic properties codify them to ignorant eyes. This is why I love Nyaya which is about investigating and knowledge to find the truth in the Vedas. As Atma and reincarnation science will likely stay neutral on those subjects all we need to prove is how scripture provides the mathematical possibility for it to occur. This is through circumstantial observation. However, the Pramana of postulation which I refer to is weak due to many other possible conclusions which can be derived by postulation.

Comment: In regards to spiritual authority the Rishis are supreme and unless you experience it yourself they have Sabda or reliable testimony on their side. In the same way, scientists have empirical testimony on their side. Until however, you can perceive or know what they say is true. Either you accept their model based on their perceptions or you leave the faith. This is for cases when things aren't provable by traditional means.

Comment: For example, the Bhagavad Gita has helped me out in life, but to me, its reliability comes from certain circumstances and perceptions that allowed me to feel like a guiding force is with me and while many things could be explained as coincidence my faith or trust that a higher being did it is why I believe. However, I acknowledge my grounds are in trust, and until everyone else can perceive what I can my evidence is anecdotal.

Comment: It would be the same for scientific theories if not for the fact that the majority of people can perceive it (utilizing machines) hence it became reliable testimony. This is why in my opinion it's good to get more and more rishis and yogis who can experience these spiritual events. One's direct perception if done correctly is the best proof. When the majority can have similar perceptions or experiences it becomes reliable testimony and eventually fact unless it is proven wrong somehow.

Comment: Those who accept the testimony of god or the rishis should be due to the fact they are experts on the spiritual if you believe in such I do, because of my personal experience, but I cannot impose my conclusion based on my experience unto you. Postulation is good when the majority is unable to perceive your argument although weak.

Comment: To beginwith, there is no conflict between shruti and smriti. There are only differences like if shruti says 10 days of impurity is to be observed, one smriti might say observe 9 days of impurity and another smriti might say observe 11 days of impurity. This difference to accommodate practical challenges when following shruti as-is and not an intention to conflict it. This is explained in manusmriti itself using example of agnihotra performance time

Comment: *"Those who accept the testimony of god or the rishis should be due to the fact they are experts on the spiritual if you believe in such I do, because of my personal experience, but I cannot impose my conclusion based on my experience unto you"* - just as vaccine-takers cannot impose their conditions to take vaccine on the anti-vaxxer movement, right ? @Haridasa

Comment: @mar Indeed while there is proof both ways that vaccines may be harmful or non-harmful the intended effect of the vaccine is simply to help prevent Covid. If you choose not to take it and trust it that's on you. That being said with Flu Vaccines their is data to show it significantly lowers the chance of getting the flu.

Comment: exactly - the intended effect of rishis/smritis/scriptures is to make you happy. if people choose not to trust it, that's on them. in fact, people were OK with forcing others to take vaccines cos their *opinion* to not trust it, made them a walking hazard to others. similarly, we should force others to listen to scriptures cos their refusal to not trust it makes them a much worse hazard to others.

Comment: _"we should force others to listen to scriptures cos their refusal to not trust it makes them a much worse hazard to others"_ - @mar

Where else have we heard that one before, I wonder?

Comment: @tejasvi88 - *"Where else have we heard that one before, I wonder?"* literally just couple years ago - when scientists forced their 'scripture' on the masses to take vaccines (which is OK imo), and boosters and prevented them from traveling even for emergencies. It was forced untouchability - but when a gora white coat says it, it's ok, but when your own ancestors say it, it is 'regressive 15th century'

Comment: @tejasvi88 - *"I wonder?"* - smart, are we ? you mean, how Muslims do not drink alcohol, so we should all drink it, just to BE DIFFERENT ? the difference between conservative religions is in the philosophy, not in tapasya/sense-control. The more you constrict a spring the higher it jumps. Youngsters need to realize that all their chest thumping about how Hinduism is liberal/secular is a recipe for its downfall. You need both an iron hand and a bleeding heart. Either one alone and your religion/society is doomed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No Manusmriti is not altered.

- The fault is in the eyes of those whose views have been brainwashed
  by the Abrahamic educational approach of the occidentals.
- The fault is in the eyes of those who are trying to equate a pig and
  a cow(trying to equate a Chandala and a Brahmana).
- The fault is in the minds of those who are propounding the Western
  notion that all men are born equal which is 
  against the Vedas.

When a person obtains birth in a comparatively, lower class family or a high class family, it is for his own good and not an act of unjust because he is, merely, rewarded that jati due to his good or bad deeds in his previous birth. Now, he has an opportunity to ascend to higher stages in a sequence. Short-cut methods do not work in the Vedic system. So Manusmriti is correct when it degrade low caste people.

The super-imposed fraudulent notion that Manusmṛti has been
mutilated and modified a number of times is just a myth created by Arya Samaj since they can't accept the original teachings of Hindu Dharma. Before the arrival of British in India(in 18th Century AD) no Hindus ever considered
that his Vedic scriptures and texts are mutilated and modified. How can
Manusmṛti be mutilated when Bhagavad Geeta  cannot be? All verses of Geeta are,
till now, accepted as comprising the original form of the text and all 20+ 
classical Sanskrit commentaries (by commentators belonging to diverse
Vedic sects) on Geeta have accepted the same version of the text despite
Gītā being written.

Similarly, **when Manusmṛiti has more than 6 commentaries available till date and all the commentators have accepted the same version of the text and have shared same views in their interpretation with very trivial variance of opinion, it is, totally, idiotic to say that the text has undergone any mutilation.** After all, these commentators were highly proficient scholars in the dharma-
Shastra as trained by the Srauta and smartta traditions.

Comment: -1 Unlike most major religions, Hinduism does not have a core dogma or doctrine. This answer presents an obscure aspect of it.

Comment: I thought there were different lengths of manuscripts found and kings were allowed to amend it from my answer, so please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: @tejasvi88 The Vedas are a core doctrine and must be accepted as authority to be a part of the Vedic religion ie Hinduism. Otherwise, you're not a Sannatani or Hindu. How you see the Vedas as authority and the way you interpret them is free, however, and up to debate per the six current orthodox schools of thought.

Comment: All Hindus don't belong to vaidika sampradaya  only mimamsa/vedanta sects are vaidika sampradaya. Manusmriti is for vaidika sampradya only and doesn't apply to others. Among Hindus most brahmins, some vaishyas and few kshatriyas belong to vaidika sampradaya and others belong to folk cults. Manusmriti actually gives more freedom and luxury to shudras  etc than to brahmin. In manu smriti, there are only 10-15 rules for shudras but for brahmins there are 100+ rules.

Comment: Also don't get confused by shudras not allowed vedic education  they are allowed vocational education. For brahmins, kshatriya and vaishya professions are restricted to teaching  military and agriculture whereas a shudra  pratiloma etc have all vocational professions like architecture, construction, labour, transportation,etc.  which are major sources of revenue and economy. Thus in a manusmriti society shudras, pratilomas etc.are far richer than brahmans and lead a more luxurious life.

Comment: Upper caste are not allowed to choose these professions as they are reserved for shudras. If a upper caste enters these, they lose their caste status as per manusmriti. The plight of brahmins in a manusmriti society is no different from low wage earning government employees of modern Era.

Answer (score 7):

Dr. Surendra Kumar of the Arya Samaj has written a concise and critical commentary of the "Manu Smriti".  A scanned version can be located on-line via Google.  In this commentary, Dr. Kumar states that spurious interpolations have been made to the original text of the "Manu Smriti" over time.  The interpolated verses seem to be written in a different style of Sanskrit and they also tend to be "irrelevant and out of context but also thematically discordant".  These interpolated verses were added to the original manuscript by various interpolaters throughout history who had vested interests in maintaining socio-economic and political power.

In his critical analysis, Dr. Kumar concludes that the original verses seem to embody Maharishi Manu as "a legal luminary and religiously righteous sage".  These original verses embody "noble and just laws" of the time-period as well as displaying "due considerations to a man's potentialities, actions and abilities".

In brief, it seems as though the "Manu Smriti" discusses noble and well-balanced principles on the one hand, while other verses embody extremely objectionable principles (which seem quite anti-Manu in essence).  These other verses also seem to be written in a different style of Sanskrit and seem out of context in the overall flow of the manuscript.  Hence, the probability of interpolation of verses by vested groups is quite high.

In the end, I agree with Dr. Kumar's conclusions.  Maharishi Manu was a stellar shastrakar and smritikar during the epoch of monarchy.  I highly doubt that such a brilliant individual would include paradoxically contradicting verses within the same manuscript.

It is true that we cannot import all of the original verses of Maharishi Manu to our contemporary pluralistic society (founded on democratic principles).  However, there is much within "Manu Smriti" which can be studied and emulated.

Dr. Surendra Kumar's arguments can be found in "Opposition to Manu: Why".  It is published by the Arsh Sahitya Prachar Trust (Delhi). A copy of this concise booklet has been scanned online; one can find it easily via a Google search.

I'll end this response with a very relevant comment from Dr. Surendra Kumar (from the "Foreword" section of the booklet):

"No system in the world is completely foolproof or wholly acceptable.  Even the present social and political system is not perfect.  If some flaw creeps into the system then it can be remedied.  Our ancient saints and sages have suggested to us a panacea for tackling such unwarranted situations:
[Sanskrit verse quoted from Taittiriya Upanishad, I-II-2]
This means that good actions of others should be embraced and imitated and not the rest."

Comment: I stated in my answer above how the Manu Smriti was meant to be changed. May interest you, but both those sources seem to be woke and liberal Hindus I suggest you look at critical interpretations and supportive ones from orthodox schools.

Answer (score 0):

Manusmriti is not canonical scriptural text in shiava, vaishnava and shakt traditions.

Only in few smarta and other sects-  manusmriti will be considered among religious scriptures. In those sects, also it is not primary source, but only secondary text.

Comment: Manu smriti and other dharma shastras are also respected by the sects you have mentioned. The injunctions  in the text are followed while doing nitya karmas (daily rituals). It is not right to say they don't consider Manu smriti as a religious text.

Comment: Read commentaries on the Vedanta sutra by several Vaishnava traditions and they all quoted from Manu-smriti. It's accepted Dharma sastra scripture.

Comment: I have mentioned that it is "not" canonical scripture

Comment: This seems like a comment. Please add some sources.

Comment: It is not a scripture that defines the philosophy, but it is respected as a source of authority, and the daily rituals and practices are followed.

Comment: @SayNoToCensorship btw why are you so named? This stack exchange has answers ranging from skeptic to devoted ie some are critical and others are supportive. No biased censorship is on this platform as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

The people complaining about the Manusmṛti base their accusations on the completely unfounded notion that it is meant for our time. Smṛti means to remember which suggests it's a memory of something from a distinct time. It is still useful because it is still pretty close to the truth and answers some important questions about other texts.

Clues that it is completely not meant for today include:

- Probably the most important. **The Sarasvatī river flows clear to see**

सरस्वतीदृशद्वत्योर्देवनद्योर्यदन्तरम् ।
तं देवनिर्मितं देशं ब्रह्मावर्तं प्रचक्षते ॥ १७ ॥

sarasvatīdṛśadvatyordevanadyoryadantaram |
taṃ devanirmitaṃ deśaṃ brahmāvartaṃ pracakṣate || 17 ||

The region lying between the divine rivers Sarasvati and Dṛṣasvatī which has been created by the gods,—they call ‘Brahmāvarta’—(17)

- The decision-makers are somehow able to tell someone's Varṇa, which has been established as very hard to do (although Virāṭa seems to be able to do it pretty well somehow).
- The following verse suggests food is free at this time due to the lack of pay or self-cooking. That implies a very different world.

अन्नमेषां पराधीनं देयं स्याद् भिन्नभाजने ।
रात्रौ न विचरेयुस्ते ग्रामेषु नगरेषु च ॥ ५४ ॥

annameṣāṃ parādhīnaṃ deyaṃ syād bhinnabhājane |
rātrau na vicareyuste grāmeṣu nagareṣu ca || 54 ||

Their food should be given to them, through others, and in a broken dish; they shall not wander about in villages or cities during the night.—(54)

(By the way, the first line here misses out some of the Sanskrit meaning. Meṣa means ram/sheep. Anna is used to mean food, but especially rice (kind of like Chinese). So Annameṣa translates as rice and meat of ram/sheep dish, presumably to show the quality of food given. The sanskritdictionary.com definitions for deya and syāt are pretty self explanatory. Bhinnabhājana could translate as broken dish, or it could mean processed food in reference to the cooking and diving process. Thus, I think it means: **A rice and ram/sheep meat dish (or a like substitute), [word praising the supreme god in the form of Anna] should be given to them. Perhaps (the person implementing this) could process it.** It's safe to say this society is massively more wealthy than our own to afford this and it not even being a big deal to find funds.

Thus, when learning the Manusmṛti discern using your honest judgment what is true forever, what is similar to the truth now, and what does not apply anymore. Also, some verses make it obvious they are supposed to be true forever.

One prominent use of the Manusmṛti is as a companion text to Mahābhārata as many of the terms in the Manusmṛti are used in the Mahābhārata, but with much more of an explanation in the former.

The translation while probably well-intentioned, translates some qualifying terms weirdly, which has a knock-on effect on the meaning of some important verses, so you should look up the Sanskrit yourself. Sometimes it greatly changes the meaning.

Sources:

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc145593.html

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201787.html

Comment: ——It could be annam+esha—which takes the sheep out of question..

Comment: Wondering if the verses above are for the general population or specific Varnas? Context, please!! :) Also Mahabharata from what I have seen has some differences from the Manusmirti in terms of laws since it is more reformative.

Answer (score 0):

Manu-Smirti is simply an old law code and not a religious text even if it was influenced by religion. In Vasistha Dharmasutra it states in chapter 1 verse 17 that, "Manu has declared that the (peculiar) laws of countries, castes, and families (may be followed) in the absence of (rules of) the revealed texts." https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vasistha-dharmasutra/d/doc116363.html

Hence the Dharmashastras if by the use of knowledge fail the test of time may be refuted, reinterpreted, or amended. This is supported by Manu-Smirti 4.176 "He shall avoid such wealth and pleasures as are opposed to righteousness, as also righteousness if it be conducive to unhappiness, or disapproved by the people." https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200281.html

That being said one should read the smriti in Sanskrit, before judging the whole text as evil or good. It is an ancient law -book and it was influenced by the situation and hardships of the people in that time. That being said it does support capital punishment and other laws which may be against modern society and because it was likely amended by rulers it's not the original. One should look at it as more of a prototype than a literal law for a Vedic kingdom.

Before studying Dharmashastras study the hardships and situations the people of those times faced. Study the culture, psychology, and daily lives of noble and regular people. Think about the influence of clergy and religion. Study the economic situation and anything else that sets the scene. Then using this reconstructed setting make realistic hypothetical situations and conflicts that may occur. Next, test the laws and see how well they assert to that situation this will tell you how effective the laws were. Grade them based on the situation then and not the one now. See if you can come up with better laws or amendments to such smirti and your reasoning behind them and their impact on the situation. To learn from the smirti in today's time is to take the methodology of it which insight is gained by testing it as I stated above. See if this methodology can somehow be used to make modern laws. Note methodology means the method or reasoning behind why the laws were made. This is the proper way to study them in my opinion.

Comment: For hypothetical situations think weather incidents, foreign invasion, rebellion, unwillingness to work, and competition on who gets a job leading to undesirable jobs which may be needed not being done. Think about crimes and their impact on society based on this situation. Along with the impact on the victims. Think of the criminal, who is he and how would people react if he were to be arrested? Most importantly don't let bias affect majorly look through the lenses of the past and why we no longer need those laws either due to technology, global cooperation, or a shift of ethics/morals.

Comment: "Hence the Dharmashastras if by the use of knowledge fail the test of time may be refuted, reinterpreted, or amended. This is supported by Manu-Smirti 4.176 " - this verse doesn't invalidate any of the established smriti laws. It applies only for new scenarios which are not addressed by smriti. Best example would be modern day dairy industry cruelty to cows  now this is a new issue which obviously  is not covered by any of the smritis. So one has to use own judgment to solve this issue - like milk is required for rituals but at the same time milk available to us is tamasic

Comment: @ekAntika in certain cases it might. Also why just dairy all industries have wronged animal care and milk we have is pasturized and healthy to drink? Also I never said Manu Smirti is invalid, but at the same time it was made during the abscence of holy scriptural rulings which also provide these restrictions. At the end of the day one should use his or her own judgement and see which rules can be applied today and still followed.

Comment: Coming to the main point, criticism of manusmriti is a politcal propoganda started by ambedkar. manusmriti applies only for vaidika sampradaya, for others manusmriti doesn't specify any laws. Castes like dalit etc are not under the scope of manusmriti. If someone wrongly applied manusmriti on dalits, it is that person's fault and not the fault of manusmriti. Vaidika sampradayas (including shudras under them) never complained about manusmriti as manusmriti was liberal on lower castes and rigid only when one goes higher in the caste (read my comments in other sections)

Comment: the fundamental point is there is no contradiction between shruti and smriti. Smriti has no intention to contradict or reform anything. Smriti gives workaround to practical challenges like if agnihotra cannot be performed in specified time as mentioned by shruti then the next alternative is X, Y, etc. which is what is referred as "absence of holy scriptural rulings". "Ātmatuṣṭi" is not about overriding rules, it is about reapplying principals associated with these rules, hence the rules are 100% relevant as a reference point.

Comment: @ekAntika in many cases yes, but in many cases smriti deals with statecraft which is no longer applicable in today's setting or may be different due to the situation.

Comment: yes some things like statecraft, etc. not applicable today but in future you never know as time follow the cycle of satya > treta > dvapara > kali > satya > etc. Hence not a bad idea to be prepared and aware of all rules.

Comment: @ekAntika I stated before the possibility however of interpolation or amendment. Also, you are right regarding daily rituals they must be followed by Brahmins who have learned to purify the whole community. That being said Brahmins must first learn the material and teach it.

Comment: if a person says "I am **unable** to follow rule(s) so I **will follow it this way**" it is OK as Ātmatuṣṭi. 

But if a person says "I **will not** follow rule(s)" or "**Rule(s) are bad**", then there is no excuse.

Comment: @ekAntika You see I agree with you in that sense. Even if you cannot perform all the rules you still should do the best you can to do your traditional duty.