# Have Hindu philosophies dealt with subjective vs. objective pramana (evidence)?

Tags: philosophy, pramana

For example, most people who have eaten a mango will say it tastes sweet.

Suppose a foreign person visiting India has never tasted a mango. He has also been advised by his countrymen that bright-looking fruits are usually poisonous. And that people native to India might have a better suited immune system to native fruits, so just because they can eat it doesn't mean he can eat it.

An Indian now offers the foreigner a mango, and claims it tastes sweet.

The foreigner asks for 'PROOF' that it tastes sweet.

The Indian simply says 'Eat it and you'll know'

The foreigner replies 'I will not eat it until you can prove that it tastes sweet ? Only then I will eat it'.

IMO, even if the Indian is well-versed in chemistry/biology and does experiments to show the presence of saccharine molecules in both the mango, and in sugar (an item which the foreigner HAS eaten), the foreigner might still say 'There is no proof that the mere existence of saccharine makes something sweet, especially in combination with other molecules/fibers of the fruit'.

The Indian gives up. Now, the foreigner claims to the world that the Indian's claim of 'Mango is sweet' is unfalsifiable, while conveniently hiding the fact that he has imposed the 'will-not-taste' condition on it.

Have any treatises dealt with the issue of a truth that is subjectively (for me) verifiable, but not objectively (for others) provable ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92443/discussion-on-question-by-ram-have-hindu-philosophies-dealt-with-subjective-vs).

Comment: You are making the foreigner look stupid.

Comment: Anyway, you can try asking a scholar of navya nyAya. They have the most advanced logical formulations among Indian philosophies.

Comment: @LazyLubber, is that a crime ?

Comment: Its unrealistic. It is like setting up and attacking a strawman.

Comment: @LazyLubber, good. now you know how some people feel when others refuse to follow the instructions laid down for proof yet keep asking for proof.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point.

Comment: @LazyLubber, a person asking for proof that mango is sweet but refuses/too-lazy to taste it, is exactly the same as a person asking for proof that astrology is true but refuses/too-lazy to study it, is exactly the same as a person asking for proof that God exists but refuses/too-lazy to do penance.

Comment: @ram:Any scripture of any Dharma/religion cannot prove PERSONAL EXPERIENCES. Vedic Literature is basically about SPIRITUALITY, which are  personal experiences. So if you modify your question, calling for clarification, without scriptural base, you may get it

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, what are you talking about.. i'm discussing difference between science and religion, not whether religion can prove personal experience.

Comment: @ram: sorry my friend!  You are comparing personal experience with science.  Please check

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, I am telling you that science is the same as personal experience.

Comment: @ram: basically your question has a flaw,  in my opinion.   You are expecting scriptural Base for the answer , which may not be possible in all situations.   If you modify your question in that line, you may get answers.   That is what I want to convey.  I will not argue with you in this regard.  I'm leaving it to your judgement

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, the question does not have a flaw. you're misunderstanding the question, its intent and its answer.